# How to push job in specific queue and limit number workers with sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, resque, jobs, sidekiq, worker

I know we can do:

```
sidekiq_options queue: "Foo"
```

But in this case it's the Worker which is assigned to only one queue: "Foo".

I need to assign a Job (and not a Worker) in specific queue.
With Resque it's easy:

```
Resque.enqueue_to(queue_name, my_job)
```

Further, for concurrency problem, i need to limit the number of Worker on each queue at 1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch

and then:

```
Sidekiq::Client.push({
    'class' => GuidePdfWorker,
    'queue' => queue_name,
    'args'  => [my_job]
})
Sidekiq::Queue[queue_name].limit = 1
```

But you have to declare your queue_name in the config/sidekiq.yml

Comment: yes, it's a good thing, but i need to dynamic queue name, so if i have to define them in a file, it's not good solution.

Exemple: if i have games, jobs belongs to a game. I want create dynamic queue name like "game_" + game_id and push the jobs in a good queue. You undestand?

How can i do that?

Comment: I asked the same thing :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133346/how-can-i-create-sidekiq-queues-with-variable-names-at-runtime

Comment: yes, i know that, but sidekiq-limit-fetch and sidekiq-dynamic-queues are incompatibles plug-in ! I need the both but i can't :'( any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the above said functionality using the sidekiq limit fetch. You can set `dynamic queue mode` to true and specify the queues in the `Sidekiq::Client.push`

And set the `process limit` to the specific queue. We can either set the process limit or we can ignore and simply it process as per the sidekiq default limit