# How can I create sidekiq queues with variable names at runtime?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I am trying to create queues with variable queue names.

```
queue_name = "guide_" + guide['id'].to_s

Sidekiq::Client.push({
    'class' => GuidePdfWorker,
    'queue' => queue_name,
    'args'  => [key],
    'backtrace' => true
})
```

I know that I am supposed to add them to config/sidekiq.yml, but I can't, since I don't know the  value of queue_name.

When I log `Sidekiq::Client.registered_queues()` I can see my queues, but they are never processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Sidekiq Dynamic Queues](https://github.com/wr0ngway/sidekiq-dynamic-queues) gem will probably help you.

Comment: Thanks :) I wanted to use it with [Sidekiq Limit Fetch](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch) but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: same problem here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080047/how-to-push-job-in-specific-queue-and-limit-number-workers-with-sidekiq)

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a more complete, updated answer: there are plugins and extensions to Sidekiq that can do things like this, but Sidekiq is not designed to operate this way.

> I don't recommend having more than a handful of queues ... and Sidekiq Pro cannot reliably handle multiple queues without polling

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues

> the number of named queues used should be minimized.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/835

Instead, consider having a known, static, queue with a worker that dispatches based on what you'd like to be dynamic:

```rb
class GuidePdfWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: 'default'

  def perform(guide)
    # branch on guide['id'], perhaps re-queue in higher or lower priority queue?
  end
end
```